# How to add "date" xml tag android

Tags: android, xml

I want to include "date" in my application. So far, we have "DatePicker" tag in android. The xml code is as follow:

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TimeSequence"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />
```

In my screen on specific location. In the image below, i want to display my date as "2014/5/27" rather than using date picker style. I also want to allocate the position of this date as per my choice. Please give me some suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just add this code you onCreate

```
private DatePicker datePicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    //init(year, month, day, onDateChangedListener);
    datePicker.init(2014, 5, 27,null);      

}
```

Comment: I want to display date in this format "yyyy/mm/dd" on my screen. I want to replace "upper time" with the date.

Comment: what is `upper time`m did you mean `current time`

Comment: See the image i upload.Time is displayed twice. I want to replace one value of "time" with "date"

Comment: i don't know for now , sorry not me